# Why is adding toFixed() to a variable not working in this react scenario but working in another?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

In this scenario, I added toFixed() to product.price and it is working just fine.

```
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { useEffect} from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { productListCreator } from '../state/actions/productActions'

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
    const { loading, error, products } = productList

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    // Retrieve all products at reload
    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(productListCreator())
    },[dispatch])

    return (
        <>
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-5xl my-8 p-8">
                <h1 className="my-6 text-xl font-medium">digital art collection</h1>
                { loading ? (
                    <h3>Loading..</h3> 
                ) : error ? ( 
                    <h3>{error}</h3> 
                ) : (
                    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-5">
                        {products.map(product => (
                            <Product key={product._id} product={product} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

```
import Rating from './Rating'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Product = ({product}) => {
    const disabled = (product.countInStock === 0)

    return (
        <div className="card rounded shadow flex md:flex-col items-center overflow-hidden ">
            <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`}>
                <img className="mx-4 my-1 h-60 md:h-50 py-2 object-contain" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
            </Link>
            <div className="py-4 px-4 mx-4 md:mx-2">
                <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`} className="block h-28 font-light">{product.name}</Link>
                <span className="block text-lg mb-4 font-medium">${product.price.toFixed()}</span>
                <Rating product={product} />
                <button disabled={disabled} className="px-6 py-4 my-4 min-w-full bg-pink-400 hover:bg-pink-300 disabled:bg-gray-300 hover:shadow-md text-white shadow-sm rounded-sm block">
                    {disabled ? 'Out of Stock' : 'Add to Cart'}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

However, in this scenario below, it is causing an error saying "product is undefined"

```
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { productDetailCreator } from '../state/actions/productActions'
import { addCartAction } from '../state/actions/cartActions'


const ProductScreen = (props) => {
    const { id } = useParams()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(state => state.productDetail)

    // Load Product
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(productDetailCreator(id))
    }, [dispatch, id])

    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)

    // Add to Cart Function
    const addToCartHandler = () => {
        dispatch(addCartAction(id, qty))
        props.history.push('/cart')
    }

    const disabled = product.countInStock === 0

    return (
        <div className="max-w-5xl mx-auto my-24">
            <div className=" mt-8 p-2">
                <Link to="/" className="flex items-center text-gray-400 font-light">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-3 w-3 mr-1 text-gray-400" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M11 19l-7-7 7-7m8 14l-7-7 7-7" />
                    </svg>
                    Back
                </Link>
            </div>
            { loading? (
                <h3>Loading...</h3>
            ) : error ? (
                <h3>{error}</h3>
            ) : (
                <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center my-7 px-8 py-2">
                    <div className="p-5 sm:w-2/5">
                        <img className="" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col sm:w-2/5 p-5">
                        <span>{product.name}</span>
                        <hr className="my-4"/>
                        <Rating product={product} />
                        <hr className="my-4"/>
                        **<span>Price: ${product.price.toFixed()}</span>**
                        <hr className="my-4"/>
                        <span>Description: {product.description}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col sm:w-1/5 p-5">
                        <span className="price text-center">Price: ${product.price}</span>
                        <span className="text-center mt-1">Status: {product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock'}</span>
                        <div disabled={disabled} className="qty-selector disabled:hidden px-4 py-2 qty-select text-center">
                            <label htmlFor="qty">Qty</label>
                            <select onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)} name="qty" value={qty} >
                                { [...Array(10).keys()].map(x => (
                                    <option value={x+1} key={x+1}>{x+1}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={() => addToCartHandler()} disabled={disabled} className="px-2 py-4 bg-pink-400 hover:bg-pink-300 hover:shadow-md disabled:bg-gray-400 text-white shadow-sm rounded-sm text-center my-4">
                            {disabled ? 'Out of Stock' : 'Add to Cart'}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
            
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

If I had to guess, it has something to do with the order React and Javascript renders things. So Homescreen is running the productAction and calling the productList from the API. And then once it receives it, it passes it as a Prop to the  component so it is always available?

However, since ProductScreen is using useSelector to grab the state, dispatching the action to grab the product details, it is running toFixed() before the product is retrieved?

This is only a guess, I'm still new to React and trying to venture out of this tutorial.

If this is correct, what is the best practice on how to handle pricing to be always to the 2nd decimal?

I am having to apply toFixed() to everything on front end because on the backend is just serving JSON.

Comment: Product is probably not available at that time so you might want to check like you do with the loading checks. I would also recommend using the [Redux Dev Tools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) so that you can inspect your state and see if product is available or not.

Comment: Thanks you're right. I decided to change the type from Number to String on the backend only for price so Price can be exact. And use the Number() function to convert on the frontend as needed.